# sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 4 supplied

Tags: python, sql

when I run it I get: `sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 4 supplied.`

```
import sqlite3
database=sqlite3.connect("users.db")
cursor=database.cursor()
data=("first","last","email","True")
print(data)
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users_db VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s')",data)
data=cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
print(data.fetchall())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single quotes (`'`) denote string literals. Here, you're inserting four values of the string literal `%s`. If these are supposed to be placeholders from bind variables, you should remove the quotes:

```py
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users_db VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)", data)
```